# Attaching GDB debugger and logging backtraces

Tags: linux, gdb

I have been struggling for days in trying to debug my application. What I would like to do is attach GDB to a running process (using batch-silent) but log backtraces to a text file if a crash occurs. I'm able to attach the debugger without issue (gdb attach pid). But haven't been able to achieve the logging in conjunction with it running silently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> But haven't been able to

What have you tried? Example:

```
cat t.c
int main() { sleep(5); printf("Aborting\n"); abort(); }

gcc -w -g t.c && ./a.out &
sleep 0.1 && rm -f gdb.txt &&
gdb -q --batch-silent -p "$(pgrep a.out)" -ex 'set logging on' \
   -ex continue -ex where -ex quit &&
cat gdb.txt
```

This produces:

```
[1] 38218       # bash reports background process
Aborting        # process done sleeping

                # contents of gdb.txt:
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f99aeb50c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007f99aeb54028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00000000004005df in main () at t.c:1

                # bash reports process termination:
$ -bash: line 98: 38225 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out    
[1]+  Exit 134                gcc -w -g t.c && ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to attach to a running process?

If your goal is to fix crash you can enable core dumps and debug a core dump after crash happens. There are several limitations in debugging a core dump compared to debugging a live process but in your case (only seeing backtraces) it looks more appropriate. To debug a core dump run:

```
gdb /path/to/binary /path/to/core
```